# How to return type that's neither generic or concrete

Tags: generics, interface, idris

I have an interface `Foo` that contains a link to another `Foo`

```
interface Foo ty where
  other : ty -> Foo x => x
```

But when I try to implement this

```
data Bar : Type where
  MkBar : Foo x' => x' -> Bar

Foo Bar where
  other (MkFoo xx) = xx
```

my return value doesn't have the same generic type as in `Foo`, so it doesn't type check. I'm not sure how to get this to work, but for now, is there some way to remove the generic implicit type `x` from the equation, and just say "`other` will give you a `Foo` but I'm not saying what kind of `Foo`". This is a bit like a trait object in rust, or returning an interface in Python: `class Foo(ABC): def other(self): Foo`

**Context** I'm trying to implement sth like [the `source` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.source) on rust's `std::error::Error`

Comment: `Bar` *is* how you say "`Foo` but I'm not saying what kind of `Foo`".

Comment: @HTNW i'm not sure i follow. I know that I can pass any kind of `Foo` to `Bar` and the type information is lost. I don't know how then to type that value if I return it from a function (here `other`)

Comment: That's just it: you don't. You can return `Bar` from the function and unwrap it at the caller to get the stored type and `Foo` instance for that type and value of that type. But there is no language-level construct for unwrapping the `Bar` *inside* `other` and passing all those things out. You define a data type (like `Bar`) to package them up and then return that. This class can be `interface Foo ty where other :: ty -> Bar`. I.e. you can "standardize" all `ty`s down to a `Bar`. In your case I guess I'd call `Bar` `SomeError`. Then `source :: Error x => x -> Maybe SomeError`.

Comment: @HTNW thanks i understand now, but I'll need to think if this provides the API I'm after. In particular, I want to be able to pattern match on both the error and the error cause so I can act differently depending on the error types. They'll need their own types for that afaict